# Ruby: static array?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I know that in Ruby everything is an object, even literals and basic types. But I was wondering if the concept of static array exists or not.

I mean, I can do:

```
a = Array.new(3, '1')
```

but this is going to be malloc'd in the heap, it's not static. Isn't it?

I was thinking of the equivalent C/C++ style:

```
int values[1024];
```

Comment: I think it makes less sense to even think about memory allocation in Ruby. What properties of a statically allocated array are you interested in? (And are you sure you're not also thinking about automatically allocated (local) arrays?)

Comment: That's the high-level request: I'm using FFI. I want to return a huge array of ints from C++ side (it's a .so shared object lib) to Ruby. I want to return it by value (i.e. not the pointer and the length). I created a struct with the array and some other satellite infos. P.S. I've seen your blog: nice!

Comment: You might want to write a singleton object that owns a class array and write getter/setter for use with your FFI (FD: I know C++ and Ruby separately, but haven't used the ruby FFI or otherwise integrated C++ w/ Ruby).  You can instantiate and initialize the singleton in app initialization.  Normally this can become an anti-pattern because the singleton may devolve to just a global variable, but it would provide you with something that behaves like a static array in that I doubt the GC would ever touch it.  I agree w/ Joseph Mansfield though, usually shouldn't worry about memory alloc in Ruby.

Comment: There is nothing in the Ruby Language Specification that says where or how objects are allocated. It doesn't even say there has to be heap or a stack at all! You could implement Ruby with just a stack and no heap (although that would be hard) or just a heap and no stack (that's rather easy).

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's ok, but the GC mimics the behaviour of C/C++ scope rule. For example, if you exit from a function all the local variables get GC'd as it would happen in C/C++ (stack pop). If you free some dynamic allocated variable the GC's kicks in as in C/C++ when you use free(). (heap management).  Said that, how can I guarantee a variable never get GC'd? In other words, how can I make such variable globally scoped? static?

Comment: @G_G: Variables don't get GCd, objects do. An object is eligible for GC, when there are no references to it. (This does not necessarily mean that it gets GCd, only that it is allowed to do so. GC is expensive, it is typically only performed when you actually run out of memory.) So, as long as there is a reference to it, say, a global variable, it cannot be GCd. It may, however, be copied (e.g., from one generation to another in a generational GC, from one region to another in a region-based GC) or moved (in a compacting GC). The spec gives great leeway there, since different GC designs have …

Comment: … different tradeoffs, it is generally a good idea to not prescribe too much, so that the implementors can choose whatever makes most sense for their implementation.

Comment: variables get GCd as well because in Ruby everything is an object, literals too. Despite arguing how actually the Garbage Collector works, please could you explain to me how to make an object globally scoped? It's just a  matter to not lose the reference to it? thank you